# Multiple results for each individual row (one-to-many) with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a `DataFrame` where each row is an individual and each column individual attributes, how can I get a new `DataFrame` which maps each individual to **multiple** results?

I've tried doing this with `DataFrame.apply()` which seems the most intuitive – but it gives exceptions as per the example below. Adding `broadcast=False` or `reduce=False` does not help.

<sup>Below is a trivial example, obviously, but consider any scenario where each row maps to multiple rows. What's the best way to handle that? In reality, each row can map to a different number of results. This is basically computing a one-to-many relationship.</sup>

**Example**: I have a `DataFrame` dataset with the following structure where I want to, for each individual, get the three upcoming birthdays (trivial example, I know). So, from:

```
+---+-------+------------+
|   | name  | birthdate  |
+---+-------+------------+
| 1 | John  | 1990-01-01 |
| 2 | Jane  | 1957-04-03 |
| 3 | Max   | 1987-02-03 |
| 4 | David | 1964-02-12 |
+---+-------+------------+
```

to something like:

```
+-------+------------+
| name  | birthday   |
+-------+------------+
| John  | 2016-01-01 |
| John  | 2017-01-01 |
| John  | 2018-01-01 |
| Jane  | 2016-04-03 |
| Jane  | 2017-04-03 |
| Jane  | 2018-04-03 |
| Max   | 2016-02-03 |
| Max   | 2017-02-03 |
| Max   | 2018-02-03 |
| David | 2016-02-12 |
| David | 2017-02-12 |
| David | 2018-02-12 |
+-------+------------+
```

Intuitively, I would have attempted something like this:

```
def get_birthdays(person):
    birthdays = []
    for year in range(2016, 2019):
        birthdays.append({
            'name': person.name,
            'birthday': person.birthdate.replace(year=year)
        })

    return pd.DataFrame(birthdays)

# with data as my original DataFrame
data.apply(get_birthdays, axis=1)
```

However, this raises:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,2) into shape (3)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

[...]

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `groupby` version of `apply` supports `DataFrame` as return value in the way which you intended:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Max', 'David'],
    'birthdate': [datetime(1990,1,1), datetime(1957,4,3), datetime(1987,2,3), datetime(1964,2,12)],
})

def get_birthdays(df_x):
    d = {'name': [], 'birthday': []}
    name = df_x.iloc[0]['name']
    original = df_x.iloc[0]['birthdate']
    for year in range(2016, 2019):
        d['name'].append(name)
        d['birthday'].append(original.replace(year=year))
    return pd.DataFrame(d)

print df.groupby('name', group_keys=False).apply(get_birthdays).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
     birthday   name
0  2016-02-12  David
1  2017-02-12  David
2  2018-02-12  David
3  2016-04-03   Jane
4  2017-04-03   Jane
5  2018-04-03   Jane
6  2016-01-01   John
7  2017-01-01   John
8  2018-01-01   John
9  2016-02-03    Max
10 2017-02-03    Max
11 2018-02-03    Max
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Is there any reason you prefer passing a dict-of-lists over a list-of-dicts to `pd.DataFrame`?

Comment: In this case, it's just a personal preference. Dict-of-lists is more memory efficient when the lists are long; however, here the lists are short and thus your approach of list-of-dicts may be better in terms of memory overhead.