# Separate text from a csv row into multiple ones?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am having a .csv file with rows: `NAME`, `LOCATION`, `IP Address`. Row `IP Address` has many IPs in it and they are separated by a whitespace, up to 5 characters. For example:

EDITED:

```
Name,Location,IP Address
Router,China,10.10.10.1     10.10.10.2     10.10.10.3     10.10.10.4     10.10.10.5
Switch,USA,192.168.1.1     192.168.1.2     192.168.1.3
```

and so on..

I want all the IPs to be on the separate rows under the `IP Address` column. This is how I want my output to look like:

```
Name,Location,IP Address
Router,China,10.10.10.1
Router,China,10.10.10.2
Router,China,10.10.10.3
Router,China,10.10.10.4
Router,China,10.10.10.5
Switch,USA,192.168.1.1
Switch,USA,192.168.1.2
Switch,USA,192.168.1.3
```

I have been trying to do `.split()` but it is giving me an error. Can anyone please help me?

Using `csv.DictReader` to read my csv files here.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer My bad, I made a mistake during editing. But all the spaces between those IPs are whitespace of 5 characters. Just consider them as 3 different columns.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer Yes, it is just a normal csv, I have edited it manually that is why it's getting a little difficult to understand.

Comment: To second @FlorianWeimer's point, if your data is space-separated, one type of solution is appropriate.  If it's fixed-width, another is appropriate.  If it actually has commas like your question now shows, an entirely different approach will work.  Unsurprisingly, when processing data, **the precise data format matters**.

Comment: Karan: Just open the csv file in a text editor and then copy & paste it into your question. Also be specific about the error that occurs.

Comment: @martineau Got it! I never knew how to put csv data on SO like this, my bad, i didn't read the rules properly. I have edited now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the fields are indeed separated by comma, without whitespace padding, and that the IP addresses are separated by multiple spaces.  Then this will work:

```
RE_SEPARATOR = re.compile(' +')
with open(path) as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        addresses = RE_SEPARATOR.split(row["IP Address"])
        for address in addresses:
            print(row["Name"], row["Location"], address)
```

You will have to adjust the `print` function call so that it delivers the output format you need (which is not entirely clear based on your description).

If you want to remove duplicate addresses, use this instead:

```
        addresses = set(RE_SEPARATOR.split(row["IP Address"]))
```

This will not preserve preserve order.  In Python 3.7 (and unofficially in 3.6 as well), you can use `dict` to preserve ordering:

```
        addresses = dict.fromkeys(RE_SEPARATOR.split(row["IP Address"]))
```

Comment: Thanks for understanding my problem and giving the answer although, the question seemed to vague. This worked perfectly fine!

Comment: And if there were duplicate IP Addresses and I wanted to skip those iterations then should I do: 

`for address in addresses:
    if address == addresses:
            continue        
            print(row["Name"], row["Location"], address)`

Comment: I added something about suppressing duplicates.

Comment: Yes! I used `addresses = dict.fromkeys(RE_SEPARATOR.split(row["IP Address"]))` this did remove the redundant IP addresses. Thanks!  And if I have to remove the redundant IP addresses regardless of the location or Name?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to split the IP address string with its whitespaces into a list containing a list/array of IP addresses. Then explode this into a long format whereas each combination (value) is represented as a single row. I did this in one step by utilizing Pandas `DataFrame` with its `groupby` function followed by a custom `apply` function. For your question this code works:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['Name', 'Location', 'IP Address']

data = [
    ['Router', 'China', '10.10.10.1    10.10.10.2     10.10.10.3'],
    ['Switch', 'USA', '192.168.1.1   192.168.1.2     192.168.1.3']
]

#df = pd.read_csv(your_file_name)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

def extract_ip_addresses(df_group):
    row = df_group.iloc[0]
    name = row['Name']
    location = row['Location']
    grouped_data = [[name, location, ip] for ip in row['IP Address'].split()]
    return pd.DataFrame(grouped_data, columns=columns)

df.groupby(['Name', 'Location'], group_keys=False).apply(extract_ip_addresses).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This yields this result:

```
    Name    Location    IP Address
0   Router  China   10.10.10.1
1   Router  China   10.10.10.2
2   Router  China   10.10.10.3
3   Switch  USA     192.168.1.1
4   Switch  USA     192.168.1.2
5   Switch  USA     192.168.1.3
```

In your case you could read the initial data by `pd.read_csv(your_file_name)`.

Here are some detailed examples:

- [Multiple results for each individual row (one-to-many) with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482825/multiple-results-for-each-individual-row-one-to-many-with-pandas)
- [pandas: apply function to DataFrame that can return multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050003/pandas-apply-function-to-dataframe-that-can-return-multiple-rows)

For more details, please refer to the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

Comment: I have never used pandas, and i am using a function in my code here, so i am not quite sure how my iterations will be if i use Pandas. But, i'll surely try this one. Thanks!

Comment: You could add your custom code to the extract function. But I do understand that going to Pandas is a much larger step. For your case the other answer is easier and more appropriate.